# MySQL Slow LEFT JOIN Query when using a derived query for the join

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query operates on two tables: `dev_Profile` and `dev_User`.

```
SELECT
  dev_Profile.ID AS pid,
  Name AS username,
  st1.online
FROM
  dev_Profile
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      dev_User.ID, 
      lastActivityTime /* DATETIME */
    FROM
      dev_User)
    AS st1 ON st1.ID = dev_Profile.UserID;
```

There are about 11K rows in each table and this query takes close to 6 seconds to complete. I don't have a lot of experience with databases yet. I thought creating an index for `dev_Profile.UserID` would do the trick, since `dev_Profile.ID` already has an index (it's the PK) and `dev_Profile.UserID` didn't have an index, but this didn't help at all.

EDIT: The EXPLAIN output for this query:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------+
| id | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | dev_Profile | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 11521 |       |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 11191 |       |
|  2 | DERIVED     | dev_User    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 11440 |       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------+
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post results of adding keyword EXPLAIN to the beginning of your query

Comment: Sure. I've modified my question to include the EXPLAIN output.

Comment: create an index on dev_User.ID as well if it's not and make a foreign key with dev_Profile.UserID. also quit the subquery and just simply join dev_User table. 11K rows should not take 6 seconds

Comment: @mask8 Thanks. Yeah, dev_Profile.UserID will be made into a FK.

Comment: I edited your subject line to make it more helpful for other if you agree.

Comment: Yep, much more specific. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why the nested select? That might be confusing the optimizer. Try eliminating it:

```
SELECT
  dev_Profile.ID AS pid,
  Name AS username,
  st1.online
FROM
  dev_Profile
  LEFT JOIN dev_User st1 ON st1.ID = dev_Profile.UserID;
```

Comment: That did it, Joel. I still got some fundamentals to learn. Thanks a lot for your help! It's down to 0.03 secs now.

Comment: I think this is because the temp table had no indexes - thanks for adding the EXPLAIN

Comment: If you add the EXPLAIN to Joel's answer you should see that it uses key and that is looking at less rows

Comment: This query still has a lot of extra development to go, but I figured the mistake I was making here would get repeated 10 times. I'll certainly avoid temp tables if I can help it too.

Comment: I am still learning too - but High Performance MySQL is an excellent book and check out http://www.percona.com/ they have lot of good free info (plus the authors of the book)

Comment: @AdrianCornish Nice! I've been looking for such a book :)

Comment: Welcome. Never knew I knew so little about DB's just being a programmer until I started reading this. Also I should add their blog http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/